# Display text field that matches radio button when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

By default, the first radio button will be selected, displaying the first text field, and hiding the rest.
But sometimes, if I edit content, the second or third radio button will be selected. If this is the case, it's the same result, the first text field displays, the others are hidden.

I can see why it's doing it, because of `click()`. I have tried a different method using `change()` but of course that would work either.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cEaeK/220/

HTML:

```
<table width="100">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="example" value="radio_1" id="example_1" class="radio_buttons" required />
      Radio 1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="example" value="radio_2" id="example_2" class="radio_buttons" required  checked="checked" />
      Radio 2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="example" value="radio_3" id="example_3" class="radio_buttons" required />
      Radio 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<ul>
  <li id="field1">
    <div>Radio 1:</div>
    <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="" />
  </li>
  <li id="field2">
    <div>Radio 2:</div>
    <input type="text" name="field2" placeholder="" />
  </li>
  <li id="field3">
    <div>Radio 3:</div>
    <input type="text" name="field3" placeholder="" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#field2, #field3").css("display","none");
$(".radio_buttons").click(function(){
    if ($('input[name=example]:checked').val() == "radio_1") {
        $("#field1").css("display", "block");
        $("#field2").css("display", "none");
        $("#field3").css("display", "none");
    }
    if ($('input[name=example]:checked').val() == "radio_2") {
        $("#field1").css("display", "none");
        $("#field2").css("display", "block");
        $("#field3").css("display", "none");
    }
    if ($('input[name=example]:checked').val() == "radio_3"){
        $("#field1").css("display", "none");
        $("#field2").css("display", "none");
        $("#field3").css("display", "block");
    }
 });
```

Comment: It's working, but this line is hiding the wrong fields: `$("#field2, #field3").css("display","none");`, as your first selection is `radio_2`.

Comment: That's because if the radio button is not pre-selected... it should show the first text field, and hide the other two. I'll specify that in my description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work in your scenario:

```
// A function to check the items.
function checkFields(el) {
    // The radio value.
    var sel = $(el).val();

    // Toggle the fields visibility accordingly.
    $("#field1").toggle(sel == "radio_1");
    $("#field2").toggle(sel == "radio_2");
    $("#field3").toggle(sel == "radio_3");
}

$(function () {
    // On page load you call the checking passing the radio that's
    // checked by default.
    checkFields($(".radio_buttons:checked"));

    // When a radio is clicked, call that same function.
    $(".radio_buttons").on("click", function () { checkFields(this); });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cEaeK/226/)

Comment: I don't understand what `$("li[id^=field]:not(:hidden)").hide();` is for. Doesn't seem like it's needed. Works without. Could you explain it further?

Comment: You're right. It's not needed. It was supposed to hide all the `li` which `id` starts with `field` and are not hidden already. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
$('li:not(:first)').hide();
$(".radio_buttons").click(function () {
    $('li').hide();
    $('#field' + $(this).val().split('_')[1]).show()
});
$(".radio_buttons:checked").click();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cEaeK/222/)**